# passing string by reference and updating its value through function argument in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

So if i have a function like:

```
void edit(string& s) {
    //do something with s
}
```

and i use it like:

```
std::string str = "Hello";
edit(str);
```

This will update the value of `str`.

But now i have a class, in which header file has a construtor like:

```
class MyClass {

   private:
      //something
   protected:
      std::string& str;
   public:
      //something

   MyClass(std::string& s): str(s){}
};
```

and later in the source file, i calculate a string which i want to update through the string argument that was passed to the constructor, but it does not work.

Can you please give me some idea how can i make that work, such that the class variable that i assign a `std::string` value, is reflected in the argument string which was passed to the constructor of this class.

Thank you,

**UPDATE:**

With the above change as suggested (making str a reference), i get this error:

"error: str must be initialized in cosntructor base/member initializer list"

**UPDATE- SOLUTION:**

Hi, so following this approach i seem to have found the solution:

```
  class MyClass {

       private:
          //something
       protected:
          std::string* str;
       public:
          //something

       MyClass(std::string* s): str(s){}
    };
```

Later, i have:

```
string mystring;
```

`MyClass(&mystring);` and voilla it seems to wrok well.

Comment: Missing & in your member variable str... Should be reference not variable...

Comment: The string you have passed to the constructor is irrelevant. Your object has a *copy* of that string. If you don't have access to the copy, then you don't have access.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass(std::string& s): str(s){}
```

`str(s)` copies the content of `s` to `str`. Since, `str` is not a reference variable, it is a copy and doesn't affect the passed parameter. Make the class member a reference variable. But be careful with the life time of passed parameter.

Comment: thanks but if i try to declare str a reference, it does not compile and i get error uninitialized reference variable?

Comment: visual studio 2010, but isn't reference member has to be initialized right away? but okay i double check quickly

Comment: That is the purpose of initializer list.

Comment: You do **not** want reference members in your classes, ever.

Comment: @n.m. sure but can you please suggest how then i can update the variable passed as argument to the constructor of a class, if i try the same procedure with bool it works, (not reference but using poitner) but with std::string it seems to fail

Comment: If you want to update your object, provide a well-defined interface for updating your object. If you want to share the same string between many objects, consider using `std::shared_ptr`. Your `bool` example is probably not really working either, you just got lucky.

Comment: well for the boolean case, in constructor i have (bool* boolptr) and i assing another bool pointer member variable to this like bool* memeberptr; memeberptr = boolptr; and in the soruce file somewhere i do the assignment as *memberptr = true; and it reflects in the source variable passed in argument as bool b, MyClass(&b) but this approach is not working with string

Comment: Ok appologies, actually the above approach i mentioend does work, and i just tested successfully so i can update the question accordingly :P

Comment: It's great this approach works for you, but you should probably be aware that it is in general untenable and will blow up as soon as you start doing something a bit more complicated with your class. But whatever floats your boat.